# Creating indexed file Java

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I have checked Lucene's way of indexing files. But I would need to index key value pairs. Like I have many (word,sentence) combinations in a single file or few number of files. Most of the cases, it is in the single file.

I would like to search the sentence based on the word which I use for searching. What's the mechanism that I need to use with Java?

Something similar to Sequence file in Hadoop. Without parsing through entire data, we should be able to get the value for every key available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can divide the file into sentences, index every sentence with lucene document and put the file info into the document. Then you can search some word to get the sentence and the file info.

eg. `doc.add(new TextField("content", content, Field.Store.YES));`

```
`doc.add(new TextField("fileinfo", fileinfo, Field.Store.YES));`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could create index files using this. I would like to know if indexing can be done beforehand. Execution might happen later at a time(different programs and different executions). Will it be possible?

Comment: Yes. You can create a search program independently. But you must search the `Directory` that has indices that you need.

Comment: Could you please help me with using Directory. I am using RAMDirectory now. I am not able to get examples for working with Directory